# Java sessions in servlets

Tags: java, html, session

Please, tell me how can I use sessions without JSP. E.g. I have this html file:

```
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <legend class="text-info">Welcome to My Library!</legend>
                <div class="span4 offset4 well">
                    <legend>Search</legend>
                    <input type="text" id="searchDirectory" class="span4" placeholder="search for the book">
                    <button id="search" type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Search</button>  
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

If I had a JSP, I could write  session in this way:

```
<%User user = (User) session.getAttribute("User"); %>
            <h3>Hi <%=user.getName() %></h3>
```

So, please tell me how can I do this in my html file, e.g. in a **title tag**.

Comment: You'll have to use cookies to do that - http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html

Comment: And how to set cookies (assuming you are asking only for basic servlets and no fancy frameworks)- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543345/creating-servlet-cookies

Comment: Why not use JSP? Html is static file it cannot access the java session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSP or JSF is the easiest way to do this

The only ways that I can think of, that plain HTML files can be made to do this are:

- to have an `onload()` javascript function pull data from the server using AJAX;
- to have an `onload()` javascript function pull data from a cookie that is written by the server;
- to write a servlet or servlet filter that processes all of the HTML files and does more or less what the JSP engine is already designed to do (and which is a standard portable approach)

All of these are much harder to get right than just writing JSPs.

If for some strange reason you must avoid writing jsps you can do a sort of jsp solution using the third option above by using something similar and non standard like velocity but just go with jsp.